# I have trouble switching from bash to zsh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, version, zsh, osx-elcapitan

I just switched from bash to zsh, installing its latest version with oh-my-zsh.

Disclosure: I'm a newbie so maybe some stuff are pretty obvious for more experimented developers.

According to what I've read so far, I know I should redirect `$PATH`but don't know exactly what to do, as I don't really see any clear timeline and explanation about what to do (I've been through the zsh documentation, but things didn't really become clearer). I'm running a Mac on El Capitan 10.11.6. and I'm specifically having troubles installing the right ruby and rails versions.

As an example, I've installed ruby 2.3, I've executed `~rbenv global 2.3.1` but still ruby -v gives me back 2.0.0.

Can anyone please help me to do all the set up ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you run `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: yes I did @sajan, doesn't change anything

Comment: Have you started a new `zsh` session since editing your `.zshrc` file? (As an aside, changes to `path` are better added to `.zshenv` rather than `.zshrc`, because you don't need to modify environment variables in every interactive shell you create.)

Comment: Have you solved this yet?

Comment: yes @AkashAggarwal, in my case that was a bad line on my .zshrc file, that came from trying some solutions proposed online ^^so basically I would suggest to check the .zshrc file if everything is properly exported and if there is no extra line that could cause the break.

Comment: I was looking to help you out if you couldn't solve it. Glad you did :) You might as well post the answer yourself to help others who run into same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rbenv init` - it will give you instructions for [hooking rbenv into your shell](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell).

```
MaxBook% rbenv init
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.zshrc:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```